# Generate random colors for each box individually all at the same time using JQuery, HTML, and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to have each element (A square box that is generated one at a time in a row of five at a time with an id="square" tag) separately change into a random color when I click on the clickMe() function. However, only one element keeps changing while the others are left untouched after being created. I had square as a class, but this caused all the squares to change.

Can someone show me how to have each square have a random color using the clickMe() random color generator. So, if I have one square when I click the button it creates a random color for that square. If I have two squares it generates a different random color for each square at the same time. When I have three squares and only click on the clickMe() it generates a different random color for each square at the same time. This continues for as many squares I create using the cloneMe() button.

Instead I have only been able to change one square after it has been cloned or I run into the equally opposite problem of having all the squares change (using a .class element) at the same time in sync.

[JQuery/JavaScript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4UQf.jpg)

```
var myColors = ['red', 'purple', '#E84751', 'blue', 'orange', '#323643', '#97FF73', '#362EFF', '#FF6513'];

function clickMe(){
var randomize = Math.floor(Math.random()*myColors.length);
// var x = document.getElementById("square");

// var i;
// for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  // x[i].css("background-color", myColors[randomize]);
// }


     $("#square").css("background-color", myColors[randomize]);
}

 function cloneMe(){      
    $(document).ready(function(){

    // var i = 1;
    // while(i <= 5) {
        $("#square").clone().appendTo('.orange-square-container');  
        clickMe();
        // i++;

 });    
}
```

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dycQl.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Random Colors!</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<!-- <section> -->

<div class="btn-alt-container">
  <a class="btn btn1-alt" onclick='clickMe()'>Push Me</a>
  <div class="btn btn2-alt" onclick='cloneMe()'>Make More</div>
</div>

<div class="container" 

></div>

<div class="orange-square-container">
  <div id="square"> 
         <div class="content">
           Hack Reactor's Awesome :)
         </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- </section> -->
</body>
</html>enter code here
```

[What my code looks like on the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGSFj.jpg)

Thank you kindly for your responses. I hope to find answers here sometimes when I am stuck, but have been afraid to post here.

Comment: [Please do not post images of code or errors!](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. A question title should describe the problem in short, not read like your journal that describes what a fun day you had.

Comment: Could you please update the title of your question? Things like "Okay, so" and "this code" and "I am stuck" are not really giving any clue about the question. Please update it to something short that pinpoints what your question is about specifically.

Comment: A problem i noted with your code is that you trying to clone an element by the ID, and when you do that you end up with multiple elements with the same ID, ID's should always remain unique

Comment: Went ahead and made changes! @CarstenLøvboAndersen I tried to use a class. I kept running into the same problem of having multiple clones at the same time. The only way I could have one clone at a time was to use the id= tag. What would. you suggest in order to get the desired result?

Comment: @12StarlightDave Take a look at my answer and see if this is what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
var myColors = ['red', 'purple', '#E84751', 'blue', 'orange', '#323643', '#97FF73', '#362EFF', '#FF6513'];
function clickMe() {
  $(".square").each(function() {
    var randomize = Math.floor(Math.random() * myColors.length);
    $(this).css("background-color", myColors[randomize]);
  });
}

function cloneMe() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".square:first").clone().attr('class', 'square').appendTo('.orange-square-container');
    clickMe();
  });
}
```

Inside your `clickMe` function you forgot to change `$("#square")` to `$(".square")` i've moved the `randomize` into the `.each` function.

**Demo**

```js
var myColors = ['red', 'purple', '#E84751', 'blue', 'orange', '#323643', '#97FF73', '#362EFF', '#FF6513'];

function clickMe() {
  $(".square").each(function() {
    var randomize = Math.floor(Math.random() * myColors.length);
    $(this).css("background-color", myColors[randomize]);
  });

}

function cloneMe() {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    // var i = 1;
    // while(i <= 5) {
    $(".square:first").clone().attr('class', 'square').appendTo('.orange-square-container');
    clickMe();
    // i++;

  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-alt-container">
  <a class="btn btn1-alt" onclick='clickMe()'>Push Me</a>
  <div class="btn btn2-alt" onclick='cloneMe()'>Make More</div>
</div>

<div class="container"></div>

<div class="orange-square-container">
  <div class="square">
    <div class="content">
      Hack Reactor's Awesome :)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OmG! You are AWESOME thank you so much @Carsten. Truly have been up for the last 3 days trying to get this to work. I knew I needed .each and .class but I just could not figure out what I was doing wrong. So, I abandoned .each()

Comment: @12StarlightDave If it solved your problem please mark it as solved so others know what helped you

Answer (score 0):

A quick example of assigning random colors to the squares. Please note the use of classes instead of IDs.

```js
const colors = ["green", "blue", "red", "yellow", "orange", "pink", "purple"];
const button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  /* Turn the HTMLCollection into an array using spread operator */
  const squares = [...document.getElementsByClassName("square")];
  /* Give each square a random background color */
    squares.map( square => {
      const randomize = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);
      square.style.backgroundColor = colors[randomize]; 
    });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.square {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="square">Blah blah</div>
  <div class="square">Blah blah</div>
  <div class="square">Blah blah</div>
  <div class="square">Blah blah</div>
  <div class="square">Blah blah</div>
  <div class="square">Blah blah</div>
  <div class="square">Blah blah</div>
  <div class="square">Blah blah</div>
  <div class="square">Blah blah</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try below code

```
<style>
.orange-square-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: auto;
  width: 760px;
}
#square {
  flex: 0 1 20%;
  height: 152px;
}
.btn-alt-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.btn-alt-container .btn {
  border: 2px solid purple;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: table;
  margin:20px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```